# edit user data user data using livewire component from controller

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I want to pass the id from the `standard blade view` to the `livewire component view`.

I have an edit user button in the blade file, so when the user clicks on the button `bootstrap modal` (which is a `livewire component view`)  with id will open.

**//some ajax to render the table with an edit button**

```
success: function(response) {                   
    $('tbody').html("");
    $.each(response, function(key, item) {
    str += '<tr>';
    //blahh...
    str += '<a href="#" id="' + item.id + '" wire:click="edit({{ '+item.id+' }})" class="text-info mx-1 editIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal"></a>';
    //blahh...
    str += '</tr>';
    })
    $('tbody').append(str);
)};
```

if I stick to jquery I can successfully open a modal with data to edit. but I want to open the modal as a livewire component.

**livewire view**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    //blahh
</div>
```

**livewire component**

```
public function render()
{
    //some logic here to open modal with id clicked, so I can do something as below
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();        
    
    $this->user_id = $id;
    $this->first_name = $student->student_first_name;
    return view('livewire.user.edit');
}
```

any suggestion will be helpful.
I don't want to port the whole project to livewire I just want to use the livewire component for some places due to its simplicity and lesser code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [emit an event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#firing-events) from the table click using `$emit` or `Livewire.emit`.

```js
success: function(response) {                   
    $('tbody').html("");
    $.each(response, function(key, item) {
    str += '<tr>';
    //blahh...
    str += '<a href="#" id="' + item.id + '" wire:click="$emit({{ openmodal'+item.id+' }})" class="text-info mx-1 editIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal"></a>';
    //blahh...
    str += '</tr>';
    })
    $('tbody').append(str);
)};
```

And listen on your modal:

```php
public bool $open = false;

public ?int $userId = null;

protected $listeners = ['openmodal' => 'openModal'];

public openModal(int $userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;
    // you can load your user data here
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.user.edit');
}
```